# Google Cloud Vision save imagen after detect objects

Tags: php, laravel, google-cloud-vision

I am trying to save a image in my database after detect objects with Google cloud vision. I am using php, framework laravel, this is my code,

```
function detect_object($imagen){
        $path = $imagen->getRealPath();
        $imageAnnotator = new ImageAnnotatorClient(['credentials' => base_path('credentials.json')]);

        $output = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
        list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($path);

        # annotate the image
        $image = file_get_contents($path);
        $response = $imageAnnotator->objectLocalization($image);
        $objects = $response->getLocalizedObjectAnnotations();

        foreach ($objects as $object) {
            $name = $object->getName();
            $score = $object->getScore();
            $vertices = $object->getBoundingPoly()->getNormalizedVertices();
            // printf('%s (confidence %f)):' . PHP_EOL, $name, $score);
            // print('normalized bounding polygon vertices: ');
            // foreach ($vertices as $vertex) {
            //     printf(' (%f, %f)', $vertex->getX(), $vertex->getY());
            // }
            // print(PHP_EOL);
            $vertices_finales = [];
            foreach ($vertices as $vertex) {
                array_push($vertices_finales, ($vertex->getX() * $width));
                array_push($vertices_finales, ($vertex->getY() * $height));
            }
            imagepolygon($output, $vertices_finales, (sizeof($vertices_finales) / 2), 0x00ff00);
            imagestring($output, 5, ($vertices_finales[0] + 10), ($vertices_finales[1] + 10), $name, 0x00ff00);
        }

        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
        imagejpeg($output);
        imagedestroy($output);
        $imageAnnotator->close();
    }
```

Could you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you want to grab the raw binary generated by `imagejpeg()` after processing?

The only way i know how to do that is using output buffers.

instead of:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($output);
imagedestroy($output);
$imageAnnotator->close();
```

Do:

```
<?php

ob_start();
imagejpeg($output);
$imgData = ob_get_clean();
# Do what you want with imgData, like insert into a binary field in a db, write to disk, etc

imagedestroy($output);
$imageAnnotator->close();
```

If you also want to output the image to the browser, return `$imgData` from your `detect_object()` function and echo it to the browser

```
<?php

$imgData = detect_object($imagen);

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo $imgData
```

Comment: Thank you so much :-)